# Does jdbc template closes connections in case of inactivity

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, jdbctemplate

In my Spring Boot microservice I have autoconfigured JdbcTemplate.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://${DB_SERVER};PortNumber=${DB_PORT};failoverPartner=${DB_FAILOVER_SERVER};databaseName=${DB_NAME};
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

But after more that 20 hours of inactivity I see that `connection is closed` and my web service is blocked.

Does Spring Boot closes all connection in case of inactivity automatically after some time?

**EDIT 21 March**
If I don't add connection test every X minutes or before taking it from the pool does it mean that jdbcTemplate will not recreate them in cas of long inactivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 50000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

Add these values to `application.properties` file

Comment: yes, but without those values, is there any timeout after what all connections are closed?

Comment: Actually mysql server closes its connection when connection reaches its default inactive timeout

Comment: Thanks for info. Let's taks MySql. After connection is closed, if I don't add those lignes with test, does it mean that jdbc template becomes unusable? I thought that it should recreate connection but it seems that it's not a case. I see a lot of `connection closed` errors in my logs